# removing the sixth character from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to remove the sixth character from a `nvarchar` string in sql. I need to do this on every row for the column.

For example:

```
111116111111
```

The length of every record is `12` characters, so I would need to make it `11` characters and remove the `6`th.

Can anyone assist me? Thank you.

Comment: These all worked, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just do

```
UPDATE table
set    column = LEFT(column,5) + RIGHT (column,6)
```

But maybe someone has a fancier way of achieving the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
select left([ColumnName],5)+right([ColumnName],6)
```

such as below:

```
declare @Something as nvarchar(12)
set @Something = '111116111111'

select @Something, left(@Something,5)+right(@Something,6)
```

if it gives conversion errors (such as cannot convert datatype nvarchar to numeric), you may have to cast both sides of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using <kbd>[STUFF()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)</kbd> function.

```
DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(20) = '111116111111'

SELECT STUFF(@STRING, 6, 1, '')

Result : '11111111111'
```

**UPDATE**

```
  UPDATE table
  SET Column_Name = STUFF(Column_Name, 6, 1, '')
  WHERE LEN(Column_Name) = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are 2 ways to do  basing on the length we can write query like this

```
declare @Something as nvarchar(12)
set @Something = '111116111111'

select  CASE WHEN LEN(@Something) >= 12 THEN STUFF(@Something,6,1,'')
ELSE @Something END 

or else 6 value is constant then we can use replace function 

declare @Something as nvarchar(12)
set @Something = '111116111111'
Select REPLACE(@Something,6,'')
```